# Bluetooth headset won't connect after upgrade

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 17.10, headset

I've recently upgraded Ubuntu from version 17.04 to 17.10 and I have issues connecting my bluetooth headset. In case I do manage to get it to show up as connected (even though the device itself doesn't tell me that anymore), the audio controls don't actually list the device. I've tried suggestions from a few other questions around here but nothing really worked, though the `bluetooth` package wasn't initially installed after the upgrade itself. Even tried pavucontrols.
How to fix this? Thanks!

> pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=bluetooth
>   Failure: Module initialization failed

Comment: Try the pactl command without sudo

Comment: Did try that a lot of times actually, will edit OP with the result.